# Buffer within QGIS not working properly

Tags: qgis

I'm an R Programmer but I found that Qgis is better for some geo projects.  I'm having a tough time with something and I've searched.  Basically, I want to create a buffer around 5 points so that I can then sum the population for the buffer area.  The issue I'm having is that the Buffer dropdown is not in my Geo Processing Tools.  Rather I have a Fixed Buffer (QGIS v2.18.14 mac).  When I use the fixed buffer I get a gigantic circle that takes up the whole map.  Any ideas where I might be going wrong?  [image]

Comment: What are the units of the coordinate system? If degrees, and you enter a buffer distance of, say 10, then you'll get a buffer of radius 10 degrees (~1100 km)

Answer (score 2):

Most Probably your SRID of points is 4326, which is degree, minutes, seconds . You should convert the points to meter based SRID, say 3857. Then apply buffer in meters unit. Afterwards you can convert back your points to 4326.